# C# How to download a program and save it in the start up folder

Tags: c#, permissions, startup

I've downloaded the file using the WebClient namespace, but when I try to save the file to the start up folder in Windows 7, it gets denied access to save the file there.  Is there a way that I can request permission to save it there, or is there a workaround? I haven't found a good resource on the web to tell me how to get past the permissions issue.

Comment: Could you clarify your requirement? Why do you need to put it to start up folder? There may be other alternatives to accomplish the main goal. However anyways you would need security permissions that would allow the operation as it's not safe (viruses would try to do something like that).

Comment: I need to put it in start up so that it runs every time I start my computer.  I've written something that requires a password to open a folder and I want it to run on start up, but I want to accomplish this with code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run your program "runas" admin
add app.config:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```